# golang support for shared memory

Tags: c, go

I heard the slogan in golang about shared memory via communication, but here I have a need to write an application to interact with an existing application A using shared memory. Basically A writes a big chunk of data in memory (so big that it's inefficient to other other means of IPC), and wait for a program B to process it and report the result to A.

Would like to write the program B using golang due to its scriptability and speed,   but don't see the direct support for shared memory. Thought of using C interface in golang but there is a problem with passing pointers between the two languages.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE1**: 
   Forgot to mention this is on Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks for asking.

**UPDATE2**:
   Created a simple program to test the reading of data pointed to by C pointer.

golang code called "reader.go"

```
import "C"
import "unsafe"
import "fmt"

func read(filename string) string {
    f := C.CString(filename)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(f))
    s := C.testc(f)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(s))
    return C.GoString(s)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(read("tmp"))
}
```

C code called wrapper.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

char buf[0x10000];

char* testc(char* filename){
    printf("reading file %s\n", filename);
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    fread(buf, 1, 100, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return buf;
}
```

When running `go run reader.go`, got a stackdump on go (too long to include here).

**UPDATE 3**:

Find the line that caused go to crash: `defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(s))`
Without it, things works fine.

Credit: the code snippet is adapted from https://gist.github.com/jedy/3282764.

Comment: What platform?  Unix, Windows or both?

Comment: I think the problem passing pointers is more passing go managed memory to C.  If you are basically doing shm* functions (on linux), go's GC won't relocate that stuff since it not managed by the go runtime

Comment: @DavidBudworth, if I call C routine in golang to get a pointer to the shared memory region,  can I use golang code to process the data pointed to? new to golang here, but I am excited about the great features that go has to offer.

Comment: yes, we do this all the time, we have a C library that memmaps a shared file for us and hands us pointers, we just cast those pointers to a struct and it works.  Look at unsafe.Pointer, it is special and can be converted int o any type.  d := (*Quote)(vaddr) // from my code base, vaddr is: (unsafe.Pointer)(uintptr(raddr)) - hope that helps

Comment: sorry, that was maybe a little too low level, if you have a C api that returns a pointer to a struct, you can use it just normal and it's fine.  The example i had there was from my project where the memory is a big chunk of shared ram and I compute record locations and cast the to type in go

Comment: You can access C pointers just fine. Go may one day prevent the ability to pass Go pointers into C: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8310 but this will work just fine for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score -1):

I take it that you are referring to System V IPC shared memory. There is a good post in [golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/golang-nuts/posix$20semaphore/golang-nuts/zpwbWye5o7o/EuE-E6EhBAAJ) about how to go about implementing System V IPC semaphores, and much of this would also apply to the shm system calls.

You can use CGO, but it is generally better to write pure Go functions that call the UNIX system calls directly. The package at [golang.org/x/sys/unix](https://golang.org/x/sys/unix) contains many good examples of how to invoke system calls from Go without having to involve CGO. (If you do go down this path, it would be a great idea to create a CL to update that package).